# Password protect pages on a website

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection

So I hope someone can help.

I've been experimenting with .htaccess and .htpasswd to password protect a certain page on my website but, although I've got the basic principle working, I'm running into issues.

My website uses an unordered list to present various main menu items, one item of which I want to password protect. When any of the menu items are clicked I go through some javascript to hide what was previously shown onscreen and replace it with content loaded from a separate html file.

Most of the menu items are loaded from siteroot/pages/ folder.
In the case of the menu item I want to password protect the content is loaded from siteroot/pages/protected/ folder which is where I've placed my .htaccess file.

Problem is I can only seem to get the site to trigger the login alert at the siteroot rather than when the specific html file is loaded from the protected folder.

Is this because of the way I've constructed the site, i.e. all the content is essentially loaded at the very start and menu content shown or hidden dependent upon which menu item I've clicked.

If so can anyone suggest a workaround?

My thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make the ajax-call to the protected content and check the returning http-code. If it is e.g. 401 for `Unauthorized`, you can ask the user to provide the credentials and then send another request which is providing the login data.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll do some Googling on how I can achieve that.  At present this is how I respond to menu clicks:   <div class="tabcontent" id="tools"> 
          <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#linkTools').addClass('active');
     $('#linkTools2').addClass('active');
                    $("#tools").load("pages/protected/tools.html");
    </script> 
        </div>